# Add Circle with different colors Inside table data

Tags: html, css

[Here is the image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPo70.png)

I want to add circles with different colors inside the table data cells?

I have tried with CSS but the positioning was not good.

```
.circle{
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block; }
```

Do I need to create separate classes for every color?
Creating separate classes for every color makes the CSS code lengthy.

How can I achieve this

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 13px;
}

th {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #888;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 10px 8px;
}

td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Head 1</th>
          <th>Head 2</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Black</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>PEWA</td>
          <td>Yellow</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td>Blue</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>AFW</td>
          <td>Orange</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>YSW</td>
          <td>Red</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>GWG</td>
          <td>Green</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>BFD</td>
          <td>Blue</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>VHY</td>
          <td>Violet</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>GWY</td>
          <td>Grey</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>WDA</td>
          <td>Yellow</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Where is the CSS you have tried. Could you add that here to show us your attempt to achieve this ?

Comment: I have added the CSS code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `span`s for the colors and put the text inside a `div` along with it. Then use `display: flex` to properly align them and inline styles for the color:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 13px;
}

th {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #888;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 8px;
}

td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #000;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

.color {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 55px;
  max-width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Head 1</th>
      <th>Head 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>
        <div class="color">
          Black <span style="background-color: black;"></span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>PEWA</td>
      <td>
        <div class="color">
          Yellow <span style="background-color: yellow;"></span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>
        <div class="color">
          Blue <span style="background-color: blue;"></span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AFW</td>
      <td>
        <div class="color">
          Orange <span style="background-color: orange;"></span>

        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>YSW</td>
      <td>
        <div class="color">
          Red <span style="background-color: red;"></span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>GWG</td>
      <td>
        <div class="color">
          Green <span style="background-color: green"></span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BFD</td>
      <td>
        <div class="color">
          Blue <span style="background-color: blue;"></span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>VHY</td>
      <td>
        <div class="color">
          Violet <span style="background-color: violet;"></span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>GWY</td>
      <td>
        <div class="color">
          Grey <span style="background-color: grey;"></span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>WDA</td>
      <td>
        <div class="color">
          Yellow<span style="background-color: yellow;"></span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Though, if you wanted to clean-up the HTML a bit, a Sass `for` loop would be better:

```
$colors: #000000, #ffff00, #0000ff, #f5a002, #ff0000, #008000, #0202f9, #ee82ee,
    #808080, #fcfc06;

@each $color in $colors {
    $i: index($colors, $color);

    tr:nth-of-type(#{$i}) span {
        background-color: $color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I move the circles near the text?

Comment: Lower the min-width of `.color`

Comment: I have tried it not working. Can we create a sperate span class for color? 
`<span class="circle">`

Comment: I've added an example using a Sass loop if you're willing to use Sass? To reduce the width you could also get rid of the `margin-left` on the `span`s

Comment: Daniel, I have tried. Can you help me with margin-left?

 I want to move the circles near to the text like in the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPo70.png

Comment: I've edited the code in my answer to look like that @Kumar

Comment: Still, I can't control the circles. I want to move the circles to left near to the text but they have aligned right side.

Comment: That's how they are in the snippet above. In `.color` try changing `justify-content` to `center`.

Comment: Daniel, changing the `justify-content` to `center` makes the circle row position not good. How can I position all the circles in the same row position?
https://imgur.com/9lzRHMG

Comment: In the snippet above they are as close as they can be without going out of line, I don't know how much closer you could want them?

Comment: I need closer to the text. Like in the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPo70.png

Comment: That is how it is in the snippet... you'll have to do your own research and figure it out, I have no idea what you're after

Comment: Daniel, the issue is with the Firefox browser. The circles are aligned right on the Firefox browser. It was working fine on other browsers.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean!

Comment: Did you find a workaround or do you want me to try and find a fix?

Comment: Not yet for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this:

https://codepen.io/quanhvsudobo/pen/NWxEdyY

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 13px;
}

th {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #888;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 10px 8px;
}

td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    text-align: center;
}
.circle {
   height: 25px;
   width: 25px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   display: inline-block;
}

.td-content {
    display: flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
 }

 .black {
      background-color: #000;
      margin-left: 2px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shorter your code, you could consider this 2 following ways which have :

1. Set directly the `background-color` attribute to HTML, this approach will make your html longer than it should, just in case you don't want to interfere to the css file
2. Set `background-color` attribute with specific class (`.bg-green` will set `background-color` to `green`) to css file for further use, you can apply this class for anywhere in the html in order to change the background color, not only for this table html case

Another thing is, if you want to align middle something, you better wrap the text with the `tag` whose `position` either `block` or `inline-block` for easier to control. In your case, change `<td>Black<span></span></td>` to `<td><span>Black</span><span></span></td>, so if you add attribute` vertical-align: middle`to both`span`, it's gonna work.

You can take a look at the snippet below for more detail (the first two `table-row` in the table HTML is used with the first method, the other two is the second one)

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 13px;
}

th {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #888;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 10px 8px;
}

td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* custom */
.custom_table span{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; /* this attribute will middle align all the "span" tag at same level */
}
.custom_table .circle {
    margin-left: 5px; /* spacing the circle and the text */
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.bg-blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

.bg-orrange {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<table class="custom_table">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Head 1</th>
          <th>Head 2</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td><span>Black</span><span class="circle" style="background:black;"></span></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>PEWA</td>
          <td><span>Yellow</span><span class="circle" style="background:yellow;"></span></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Data</td>
          <td><span>Blue</span><span class="circle bg-blue"></span></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>AFW</td>
          <td><span>Orange</span><span class="circle bg-orrange"></span></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Hope this would help